# Is there a way to get system time (time only not date) using c++

Tags: c++

First thing I tried was `system("time")`. It gave me the time, but then it asks me for input (???).

I also tried `time(NULL)`, but it gives me the current date as well. I just need the time (hours, minutes, seconds), not the date. I did use `<ctime>` and `tm_sec`, `tm_min` and `tm_hour`, but I need to use pointers for those, which I'm not allowed to use in this case.

Comment: Don't *ever* use `system()`. It's a security nightmare.

Comment: What's wrong with using `time(NULL)` with `localtime()`/`gmtime()`, and just *ignore* the date fields? What is the REAL issue you are having here? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) to me. "*I need to use pointers for [`tm` fields], which I'm not allowed to use in this case*" - huh? The only pointer in this case would be the `tm*` returned by `localtime()`/`gmtime()`.

Comment: The arbitrary constraints become curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto asTimeT = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time); // timestamp since epoch
    std::cout << asTimeT << std::endl;

    // i don't know what you mean by cannot use pointers.
    // std::localtime and std::gmtime return pointers
    auto formattedTimeLocal = std::put_time(std::localtime(&asTimeT), "%H:%M:%S"); // HH:MM:SS localtime
    std::cout << formattedTimeLocal << std::endl;

    auto formattedTimeUtc = std::put_time(std::gmtime(&asTimeT), "%H:%M:%S"); // HH:MM:SS UTC
    std::cout << formattedTimeUtc << std::endl;
}
```

Get current time with [std::chrono::system_clock::now()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now)

Convert to [time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) which is "the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC"